# Displaying thumbnails of images (present at different locations in the sdcard) in a listview

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have several images present in different folders in my sdcard. I would like to display a list of thumbnails. So what I have done is while rendering any row in the list I read the file in an input stream, get the byte array, decode it to obtain a bitmap and set it in an imageview.

So far so good. But when I scroll the list, the list scrolls in jerks. I believe this is because decoding a bitmap from byte array takes some time. What I would like to know is that, is there any optimization which I can do to improve the performance, or better still is there any better method to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Are you caching the images somewhere like a WeakReference after pulling each one?

Comment: no. caching would lead to a increase in heap size and my app can't afford that when there are say 100 images to be displayed

Comment: If you cache with a weakreference collection it will dispose when needed and not be an issue. check out the shelves project, there are some great examples of a weak reference and a fastbitmapdrawable http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/util/ImageUtilities.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way in my opinion would be to add them to your resources folder as a drawable if you can. Then you can access them as a R.drawable system resource way faster.

```
ImageView iv;
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable..));
```

Comment: I can't put the images in the resource folder, since the number of images will change from time to time. Also this would tend to increase the app size significantly